# Dictionary not letting me .get() a given key

Tags: python, dictionary, sdk, attributeerror

New to coding and python!

I'm using an sdk to search a contact directory (rocketreach) programatically. Here's the problem:

```
import rocketreach
rr = rocketreach.Gateway(api_key='5f522ek578e02c8b3eace69a805bc1249218454')
lookup = rr.person.lookup(extras={'name': 'Marc Benioff', 'current_employer': 'Salesforce'})
if lookup.is_success:
    print(repr(lookup.person))
```

This returns a dictionary:

```
{'current_employer': 'Salesforce',
     'current_personal_email': 'benioff@gmail.com',
     'current_title': 'Chairman and Co-CEO',
     'current_work_email': 'marcb@salesforce.com',
     'emails': [{'email': 'm.benioff@salesforce.com',
                 'smtp_valid': 'valid',
                 'type': 'professional'},
                {'email': 'mbenioff@salesforce.com',
                 'smtp_valid': 'valid',
                 'type': 'professional'}],
     'id': 5244,
     'linkedin_url': 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/marcbenioff',
     'links': {'aboutme': 'http://www.about.me/marcbenioff',
               'amazon': 'http://www.amazon.com/gp/pdp/profile/AZGYQG724J6ON//190-5748375-2756131',
               'angel': 'https://angel.co/benioff',
               'angellist': 'http://www.angel.co/benioff',
               'crunchbase': 'https://www.crunchbase.com/person/marc-benioff'},
     'location': 'San Francisco, California, United States',
     'name': 'Marc Benioff',
     'phones': [],
     'profile_pic': 'https://d1hbpr09pwz0sk.cloudfront.net/profile_pic/marc-benioff-4492e698',
     'status': 'complete'}
```

But when I try and retrieve the value under the 'emails' key using .get, I get an error:

```
example = repr(lookup_result.person)
example.get('emails')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#20>", line 1, in <module>
    example.get('emails')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I don't get why.... Would appreciate the help :) Thanks!

Comment: `repr(lookup_result.person)` will return a `str`, and *'str' object has no attribute 'get'*

Answer (score 0):

In `example` that you included in the question have printable representation of the given object that is `lookup_result.person`.

You can read more about [repr](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html?highlight=repr#repr)

You have to access the actual object. You can do the changes like this:

```
example = lookup_result.person
emails_list = example.get('emails')

print(emails_list)
```

Output will be like this:

```
[
    {
        "email": "m.benioff@salesforce.com",
        "smtp_valid": "valid",
        "type": "professional",
    },
    {"email": "mbenioff@salesforce.com", "smtp_valid": "valid", "type": "professional"},
]
```